# How to create OneNote 2010 section

Tags: c#, xml, onenote

How can you create a new section in a OneNote 2010 notebook with c#? According to the [API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg649853%28v=office.14%29.aspx) there is no method to do so. But there is a CreateNewPage Method so I wondering if there is something similiar for sections? If not, how can this be achieved except for manipulating the XML files (which is a task i'd like to avoid since I'm not experienced in it)?

Comment: If the API indicates there is no method, that should answer your question, you can only create new pages.  You could in theory look at the XML to figure out how its done.  I would simply write my own method to modify the XML code for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is code snippet from my add on:

```
public bool AddNewSection(string SectionTitle, out string newSectionId)
        {
            try
            {
                string CurrParentId;
                string CurrParentName;
                string strPath;
                CurrParentId = FindCurrentlyViewedSectionGroup(out CurrParentName);
                if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(CurrParentId) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(CurrParentName))
                {
                    CurrParentId = FindCurrentlyViewedNotebook(out CurrParentName);
                    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(CurrParentId) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(CurrParentName))
                    {
                        newSectionId = string.Empty;
                        return false;
                    }
                    strPath = FindCurrentlyViewedItemPath("Notebook");
                }
                else
                    strPath = FindCurrentlyViewedItemPath("SectionGroup");

                if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(strPath))
                {
                    newSectionId = string.Empty;
                    return false;
                }

                SectionTitle = SectionTitle.Replace(':', '\\');
                SectionTitle = SectionTitle.Trim('\\');
                strPath += "\\" + SectionTitle + ".one";
                onApp.OpenHierarchy(strPath, null, out newSectionId, Microsoft.Office.Interop.OneNote.CreateFileType.cftSection);
                onApp.NavigateTo(newSectionId, "", false);
            }
            catch
            {
                newSectionId = string.Empty;
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
```

Basically what I am doing here is to get the path of currently viewing Section Group or Notebook and then adding new section name to that path and then calling OpenHierarchy method. OpenHierarchy creates a new section with title provided and returns it's id.

Following is where I create a new section and Navigate to it:

```
onApp.OpenHierarchy(strPath, null, out newSectionId, Microsoft.Office.Interop.OneNote.CreateFileType.cftSection);
onApp.NavigateTo(newSectionId, "", false);
```

So can write something like:

```
static void CreateNewSectionMeetingsInWorkNotebook()
    {
        String strID;
        OneNote.Application onApplication = new OneNote.Application();
        onApplication.OpenHierarchy("C:\\Documents and Settings\\user\\My Documents\\OneNote Notebooks\\Work\\Meetings.one", 
        System.String.Empty, out strID, OneNote.CreateFileType.cftSection);
    }
```